# How to use theme overrides with nested elements?

Tags: material-ui

If I adjust the size of a button in the theme, like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            fab: {
                width: 36,
                height: 36,
            },
        },
        MuiSvgIcon: {
            root: {
                width: 16,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Then the button and the icon appear at the size I want.  However this affects *all* icons, whether they're inside a button or not!

How can I say that I only want the `MuiSvgIcon` properties to apply when the element is found inside a `MuiButton` element?

Comment: is there away to give a class to the element you apply?

Comment: @Roysh: I could put a class name on, but I'd like to avoid it if possible so that I don't have to keep remembering to add it on to every single button.  Feel free to post the class name option as an answer though.

Comment: well, if you add a class then you can apply css to it

Comment: If you can supply your whole code (i.e. the html and css) or post a fiddle, I can try to solve this using css only

Comment: The best approach is to use composition to create a custom variation of the Button component that you can reuse anywhere is your project. Is your goal to customize the styles (and icon size) for the floating action button, or all buttons?

Comment: @LukePeavey: I would like to adjust all buttons, with the floating ones having one size and potentially the other (raised) buttons having a different size.  Creating a `MyButton` would work, but it would be nicer if I could just use the existing `Button` and have them all change to reflect the theme's design.

Comment: @Malvineous In that case, i can't think of anything better than your solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Well I've worked out one way to do it, but it's not ideal because it relies on the internal structure of the `MuiSvgIcon`.  But it might serve as a starting point for someone else.  Better answers are most welcome.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            fab: {
                width: 36,
                height: 36,
                '& svg': {
                    width: 16,
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

It works by applying a style to the `<svg>` DOM element inside the JSX `<Button variant="fab">` element.

Comment: Do you know how to target nested `<Button/>` that has this class pattern? `MuiIconButton-root-<number>`.

Comment: Heureka! I figured it out. This is how I made it work: `MuiInputAdornment: {root: {'& button': {color: '#bada55'} }}`

Answer (score 4):

It's not documented anywhere unfortunately, but you can use any sort of CSS selectors to help.  Use the "attribute contains" pattern with the class attribute itself to target descendants:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            root: {
                // Targets MuiSvgIcon elements that appear as descendants of MuiButton
                '& [class*="MuiSvgIcon-root"]': {
                    width: 16
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Note 1: ***Caution!***  Material UI minifies these classnames in prod builds by default.  If you want to preserve these classnames for prod, you will need to tweak the class generator function: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/ (see `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS`)

Note 2: with this pattern, occasionally you end having to use `!important` if there's already a competing inline style that you want to override.  If you're using `styled-components`, you can increase the specificity by using `&&` (see the [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components)).